# Why does mglData cause a BAD ACCESS exception?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, exc-bad-access, mathgl

I have successfully managed to install MathGL on Mac OS and managed to get the `mglGraph` to generate me the sample graphs. Yet when I try to use `mglData` to handle my data, it crashes with an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error. Why? Is there anything I need to do I haven't done?

I installed mathgl with cmake, make and make install (using sudo to be on the safe side). Then I added the */usr/local/include* and */usr/local/lib* paths to the project and added the *libmgl.dylib* and *libmgl-wnd.dylib* references to the project. Is there anything I've missed out? I could not find anybody else with the error (well, I found many bad access errors, but none caused by mglData). The error pops up as soon as I'm trying to construct a mglData instance, so any of this triggers the exception:

```
mglData *data = new mglData();
mglData data;
etc...
```

**EDIT**

So, here's the bare bone of my code that compiles but crashes:

```
#include iostream
#include mgl2/mgl.h

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    mglData y;   
    return 0;
}
```

The thread's call stack when it crashes is:

[image: Thread call stack]

And the values of all variables are this:

[image: Variable values]

---

**Semi-Solved** *Got it running*

After having been able to compile my project with g++, I tried changing the build settings and who would have believed it, I managed to get it running! All I did was change the *C++ Standard Library* to `libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)`. Now I'm not using the default, which is to use `libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++ 11 support)`. At the moment this seems to work fine for my Cocoa application also, but I don't know for how long :P (When using more NS* Classes I worry LLVM may be necessary?)

Still I'm very interested in how this issue can be resolved (without having to change the build settings) or whether it can't.

Comment: I don't have an answer but, if you show the stack symbols at the time of the crash, it might help someone come up with a reason.

Comment: Since you have the source code couldn't you use your debugger to find what the problem is?

Comment: @john: I tried debugging, but I can only access the library's header code since it is a precompiled library. And when I did step through the program, I reached a line saying: `0x7fff92849e8f:  movq   -24(%rax), %rdx` which is no help at all (and already highlighted as the cause of the exception by XCode) :(

Comment: @MaxZ. OK sorry. I thought when you said you'd installed with make and make install you must have the source.

Comment: @john I do have the code for mathGL, yes, but I do not have the code for `clear()` in `std::string:clear()`. Apparently that's the library where the error occurs.

Comment: @MaxZ. I think you can reasonably assume that `std::string::clear()` is bug free. The issue would seem to be heap corruption that has occurred before `std::string::clear()` was called.

Comment: haha, once again I had the exact same problem, but this answer works brilliantly! I'm so surprised there isn't a more stable OSX version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with `mathgl 2.1.2` and ran into the same problem. There's a mismatch between the run-time libraries. `Mathgl` uses **compiler default** but when creating a new commas-libe project it uses the `llvm`. Since the string is allocated in your executable via `LLVM`, but then passed to `Mathgl` which used a different run-time library.
Memory operations can fail when a pointer allocated in one library is passed to another to be freed. 
There could be structure differences as well.